# sp_whoisactive keeps returning create procedure statements

Tags: sql-server

When I run `sp_whoisactive` on my server it often shows create statements being run for stored procedures but this doesn't make any sense since the procedure already exists.

See the following example:

```
dd hh:mm:ss.mss session_id  sql_text
00 00:00:00.120 103 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempGetStateItemExclusive3]
00 00:00:00.140 274 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempGetStateItemExclusive3]
00 00:00:00.133 324 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempGetStateItemExclusive3]
```

This is from one run of `sp_whoisactive` it looks like there are three sessions creating the procedure. Is this something I am misinterpreting or if not how can I find out where this is coming from? These create statements are blocking actual inserts.

I am executing

```
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive 
     @find_block_leaders = 1, 
     @sort_order = '[blocked_session_count] DESC',
     @get_full_inner_text = 1
```

The batch being executed is (which is a stored procedure from asp.net SQL Server based session state but I am seeing the exact same thing for other stored procedures as well)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempGetStateItemExclusive3]
        @id         tSessionId,
        @itemShort  tSessionItemShort OUTPUT,
        @locked     bit OUTPUT,
        @lockAge    int OUTPUT,
        @lockCookie int OUTPUT,
        @actionFlags int OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @textptr AS tTextPtr
    DECLARE @length AS int
    DECLARE @now AS datetime
    DECLARE @nowLocal AS datetime

    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()
    SET @nowLocal = GETDATE()

    UPDATE dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    SET Expires = DATEADD(n, Timeout, @now), 
        LockDate = CASE Locked
                      WHEN 0 THEN @now
                      ELSE LockDate
                   END,
        LockDateLocal = CASE Locked
                           WHEN 0 THEN @nowLocal
                           ELSE LockDateLocal
                        END,
            @lockAge = CASE Locked
                WHEN 0 THEN 0
                ELSE DATEDIFF(second, LockDate, @now)
                END,
            @lockCookie = LockCookie = CASE Locked
                WHEN 0 THEN LockCookie + 1
                ELSE LockCookie
                END,
            @itemShort = CASE Locked
                WHEN 0 THEN SessionItemShort
                ELSE NULL
                END,
            @textptr = CASE Locked
                WHEN 0 THEN TEXTPTR(SessionItemLong)
                ELSE NULL
                END,
            @length = CASE Locked
                WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(SessionItemLong)
                ELSE NULL
                END,
            @locked = Locked,
            Locked = 1,

            /* If the Uninitialized flag (0x1) if it is set,
               remove it and return InitializeItem (0x1) in actionFlags */
            Flags = CASE
                WHEN (Flags & 1) <> 0 THEN (Flags & ~1)
                ELSE Flags
                END,
            @actionFlags = CASE
                WHEN (Flags & 1) <> 0 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END
        WHERE SessionId = @id
        IF @length IS NOT NULL BEGIN
            READTEXT dbo.ASPStateTempSessions.SessionItemLong @textptr 0 @length
        END

        RETURN 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please show us the parameters of the execution of SP_whoIsActive. I remember there was a parameter switched between showing the actual statement or the batch/procedure that contained that statement.

If I'm not wrong:

```
@get_full_inner_text = 0 -- 1-shows SP/batch, 0-shows statement;
```

should be the one.
Switch it to 0 and see if it's changing the way the output is shown.

Comment: @olle switch param get_full_inner_text to 0 and you'll see which statement is the blocker. In your case I suppose it's the UPDATE statement. See what you can do to make it faster (indexes..indexes .. or maybe indexes :-) ).

Comment: @Marian but that doesn't explain why it's executing CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempGetStateItemExclusive3] ever x minutes (not like clockwork). And that is what looks like the blocker.

Comment: @olle: it's not executing CREATE PROCEDURE TempGetStateItemExclusive3. It's executing only the procedure itself - TempGetStateItemExclusive3 with it's parameters. But the output of the SP_WhoIsActive show the complete text of the procedure TempGetStateItemExclusive3 for you to be able to have a bigger picture. Better check also with SQL Profiler to see all sessions. There you'll see exactly the executions.