# sp_WhoIsActive CREATE statement in sql_text column while executing object inside another

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, sp-whoisactive

I am running fabulous `sp_WhoIsActive` with these parameters:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_WhoIsActive
    @get_task_info = 2
    ,@find_block_leaders = 1
    ,@get_outer_command = 1
    ,@get_transaction_info = 1
    ,@get_plans = 1
    ,@destination_table = @destination_table;
```

Please, mention that parameter `@get_full_inner_text` is not SET, so it goes with default = 0. I should get only the actual statement that is currently running in the batch or procedure.

But I see statements like CREATE PROCEDURE / TRIGGER / FUNCTION in sql_text column (see picture). These objects are **EXECUTED** (NOT created) in the outer procedure (see sql_command on the picture).

[image]

And there is no query plan associated with it (in query_plan column).

I was trying to search for the meaning of such results. eg. here http://whoisactive.com/docs/10_commands/ but didn't find the answer.

[Thist post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/sp-whoisactive-keeps-returning-create-procedure-statements) mentions a different scenario, so it's not the answer.

My only guess is that these inner objects could not be retrieved from the plan cache and the compilation of its execution plans is in progress. Or how would you interpret such results?

Comment: @jericzech For advice on dealing with a question closed as a duplicate see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates. The key is to [edit] your question to make it clear *how it is different*. There is a community review process to reopen.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do my best. If I fail again I step out. My intentions are good, believe me. I see the difference clearly but it could be my English is not correct to explain or I am simply not smart enough.

Comment: More words are not always the answer. Try to provide a [mcve] and describe what you expect to see instead of what you get. People may be willing to help you understand what the tool is doing, and what options you have, if any.